# sort a column's values alphabetically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns in that I have a object type column in which values are seperated by ','. I want to sort the column's values in alphabetical order.

The dataframe I have :

```
ID    things
1     pen,car,robot
2     lamp,jug,phone
3     switch,pen,book
```

The dataframe I want:

```
ID    things
1     car,pen,robot
2     jug,lamp,phone
3     book,pen,switch
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split, sort and then join:

```
df['things'] = df.things.apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(','))))

df
   ID           things
0   1    car,pen,robot
1   2   jug,lamp,phone
2   3  book,pen,switch
```

A little benchmark against `.str` method:

```
timeit("df.things.apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(','))))", number=10000, globals=globals())
4.744999999995343

timeit("df['things'].str.split(',').map(np.sort).str.join(',')", number=10000, globals=globals())
14.570999999996275
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split with [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), sort with [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`numpy.sort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and join back the texts with [`str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), as follows:

```
df['things'] = df['things'].str.split(',').map(np.sort).str.join(',')
```

All functions used are fast vectorized Pandas/numpy functions.

**Result:**

```
print(df)


   ID           things
0   1    pen,car,robot
1   2   lamp,jug,phone
2   3  switch,pen,book
```

Comment: @Psidom  Thanks!  Learned from this  :-)